# Right-most column in grid not equal to the other columns

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm having trouble getting the right-most column of three to have an equal width to the others. Code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/tg4pts46/

There's 60px of padding (a gutter) to each column, except the last one, because I don't want gutters on the outside columns. That's what's mucking it up, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's what I mean:

```
[class*='col-'] {
    padding-right: 60px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you're saying that the right-most column should not have a 60px padding but still be the same width as the first two? Why are you removing the pad from last column?

Comment: Because the padding is a gutter, and having it there would make the grid unequal. The right-hand side would have more white-space than the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

CSS:

```
[class*='col-'] {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
[class*='col-']:first-of-type {
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}
[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/NateW/tg4pts46/8/

Comment: Right, except then the grid is no longer cantered horizontally—there's 60px more white-space on the right-hand side of the page. Also, `p` was just used to simplify the problem, each column will house all types of elements. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you change your html markup? or is this css only?

Comment: Sure, I guess I could. I was hoping to just do it with CSS though, if possible

Comment: Check out my updated answer... Is that more like what you need?

Comment: That's perfect, works a treat. Thanks so much! Legend

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you are comfortable using Table, tr and td, but it seems to solve the symmetry problem. 
td combined with the nth-child pseudo class.

```
td:nth-child(1){
    border-right:40px solid transparent;
}
td:nth-child(2){
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
}
td:nth-child(3){
    border-left:40px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SaharshSinha/89jmrtym/2/